# Drawing Inside a Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, panels

I've seen this asked a lot on this site and others, but I've yet to find a answer. What I'm trying to do is draw a series of rectangles roughly 10x10 in size on a click. So I have a button, when I click it, it will create a rectangle inside my panel using

```
 xgraphics = pnlContainer.CreateGraphics();
 xgraphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), xAxis, yAxis, 10, 10);
 pnlContainer.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(Convert.ToInt32(xAxis),Convert.ToInt32(yAxis));
 yAxis += 10;
```

It creates the rectangle then moves down, on the next click it creates another rectangle but now it's lower and so on and so forth. I'm utilizing a trick I read on here on how to get the panel to scroll by putting a panel inside a panel with autoscoll on and raise the height on the inner panel when you get to the bottom. It works great HOWEVER!!!! when the panel scrollbar appears it clears all of my graphics.

I read that I counter this to use invalidate(); But when I do this it throws an error that graphics cannot be converted into a rectangle. so what the F???

I seen on MSDN that I could do this:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{

  // Draw the rectangle...

  e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Blue, PenWidth), RcDraw);

}
```

However, this creates a rectangle using the mouse, which wont work in my situation.
In a nutshell I need to be able to create a rectangle in a panel that when it gets to the bottom it then will allow you to scroll and add more rectangles to it... It doesn't sound that hard, but I'm missing something fundamental or something and it's really starting to grind my gears! Please Help!

Comment: When you paint directly onto a control, you have to do it in the Paint handler, every time the control repaints, or your drawing will be lost. Controls repaint when they are resized, covered then uncovered, etc. You should do your painting onto a `Bitmap`, then blit that onto the control in its Paint method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good practice to use `Graphics` property anywhere other than `Paint` event. Because you don't wanna lose what you've painted after a refresh, so you must paint them whenever needed, that is in `Paint` event. So you have two choices:

**First** Create an `Image`, get `Graphics` from the image and draw your items to it, then set `BackGroundImage` property of panel to this image. This way you don't mess with painting and give it to the control itself :)

**Second** Store the data needed for drawing rectangles in some variables in scope of the form.  You may use a `List` of `Rectangle`s and `Add` to them on each click, then draw them in `Paint` event whenever needed:

```
private List<Rectangle> myrects=new List<Rectangle>;

    private void childPanel_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
      e.Graphics.FillRectangles(Brushes.Red, myrects.ToArray());
    }
```

*Remember to include this in child panel if you use the scrolling trick you mentioned*

Comment: bleh, I was afraid of that....

How would I put that example into a class so I'm able to call it? I have a draw class that I'm passing data to, to do the draw.

To do a manual draw would I just pass it sender, and some paint event? I'd like to be able to pass the array to a constructor then it calls the paint void(your example) and it does the draw. that should work... I suppose creating an image would be an easier method though.. I just really wanted it to generate on the fly.

Comment: I just tried:

 public float yAxis;
 private void pnlBlackBoard_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 10f, yAxis, 10f, 10f);
                yAxis += 10f;
                pnlBlackBoard.Height += 10;
                pnlBlackBoard.Invalidate();
            }
            
        }

which is roughly the example you gave, but it would, but as soon as I scroll off screen it gets erased again.....

Comment: `pnlBlackBoard.Invalidate()` is problematic. `Invalidate()` method is called from **Other** procedures in the program to tell `Panel` to **Repaint**. You must not include this in `Panel_Paint()` event because it creates a loop. What about `yAxis` what is this ?

Comment: yAxis is a Public int that gets incremented every time I draw. So it will look like a continuous line. I also have a xAxis. The idea is to draw a rectangle based on x,y data.

Comment: Ok I got it working! I used a boolean to control the draw so it only drew when I wanted. Also figured out the problem when I scroll off screen, I don't have an exact answer to it yet, but at least I can see it happening and know why right now. Currently the app is fighting it'self, I told it to +10 to it's height if the draw was greater then it's height but on refresh I have it 0 out the height, so now it's in a infinite fight of height and draw. That part I can handle though, the draw was the hard part. Thanks